# Accessing Cloudbees Jenkins URL without authentication

Tags: cloudbees

I have an application that monitors CI jobs, and I've added a jenkins installation to my account. Typically, this application is internal to the company I work at, but our jenkins servers aren't accessible outside the LAN.

To lookup the status of a build, I to a python urllib.urlopen on

```
http://hostname/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/json
```

then parse the json result

When trying to connect to https://webiken.ci.cloudbees.com, I get an HTTPError because the URL requires authentication. Is there anyway to configure my jenkins to be public?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use HTTP Basic authentication with your cloudbees credentials to access the API :

curl https://webiken.ci.cloudbees.com/job//api/json --user ndeloof@cloudbees.com:

Comment: …but use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API to avoid the need to use your real password.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this [wiki page](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/AnonymousAccess) on how to make your Jenkins instance public.